# Xcode Build xctestproducts with multiple test plans

Tags: xcode

I have xcode project with multiple test plans and I'm trying to build xctestproducts file using Xcode (Product > Perform Action > Build and Export Test Products), when I do that the created xctestproducts contains only the selected test plan and not all the test plans. When I use xcodebuild to create the xctestproducts file `xcodebuild build-for-testing -project *.xcodeproj -destination ... -scheme ... -testProductsPath PATH` the xctestproducts includes all the test plans. How can I achieve that with Xcode IDE? Env: MacOS 13.2.1 Xcode 14.2